# (Unity) Unable to install apk on Android after upgrading api level

Tags: android, api, unity-game-engine, game-development

I recently upgraded my android game api in unity from api level 30 to 33. After that I tried testing the build by installing the apk on my android phone but I am unable to install it now as it is showing "There was a problem parsing the package".

The earlier build with api level 30 was working fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

I tried changing the api levels to 31, 32 and 33 but still got the problem.

Also tried changing some settings in Player Settings -> Player -> Other Settings.

Comment: Raising the target api causes many bugs.
It is also very difficult.
Raising the target API step by step and repeating modifications is almost the only solution.

Comment: I found a solution! Basically, I upgraded my unity engine editor version, from 2019.4.20f1 to 2021.3.7f1. I guess the problem was rising because the editor version not supporting the higher/latest API.